# MySQL Trigger Check if Row Field Exists

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mariadb

I created a trigger on a table as follows:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER tb_ins BEFORE UPDATE ON tb
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.size <> size) THEN

    END IF;
END;//
```

The problem is, individually updating any field other than `size` gives me an error that no such field is found.

For instance:

```
UPDATE tb SET color = 'red' WHERE id = 1;
```

Gives me an error that no field is found because the update does not contain a `size` field which the trigger requires.

I need to know if there's a way to check if a specific `ROW` field exists in my trigger function. How can this be accomplished?

I need something equivalent to:

```
IF EXISTS(ROW.size) THEN

END IF;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what are you trying to achieve? As it is now your question is quite vague.

Comment: i updated with more explanation

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'size' in 'field list'` even though the field exists in table

Comment: nevermind found the answer. i assumed referencing `size`would automatically fetch old value, but i need to reference `OLD.size`. error message sucks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error isn't related to the columns referenced in the UPDATE statement.

The big problem is the unqualified reference to `size` in the trigger body. If the intent is to detect a change in the value assigned to `size`, we should be comparing the value of `NEW.size` to `OLD.size`.

---

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tb_ins $$

CREATE TRIGGER tb_ins 
BEFORE UPDATE ON tb
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NOT (NEW.size <=> OLD.size) THEN
      -- value of size column has been modified
      BEGIN END;
   END IF;
END$$
```

---

It's not valid to have nothing between `THEN` and `END IF`.  We have to have something there. MySQL tolerates an empty `BEGIN` `END;` block, so we can use that as a no-op.

It's not clear what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: i left the block empty for simplicity as i knew the problem wasnt there. i am trying to detect changes in specific columns. can you explain `<=>`

Comment: The `<=>` (spaceship) operator performs null-safe comparisons, and will return TRUE or FALSE for a comparison to a NULL value, unlike the regular `=`, `<`, `>` comparison operators that return NULL for a comparison to a NULL. The expression `a <=> b` is equivalent to the expression `IF(a=b OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL),1,0)`. Used in the trigger, it's convenient shorthand for detecting a change to the value of the column, including changes to and from NULL.