# Unknown column 'created_by' in 'field list'- trigger

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a trigger but getting error message. Any guidance from your end is much appreciated.FYI- I am beginner ....

```
CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost TRIGGER txn-trg 
before INSERT ON transactions 
FOR EACH row 
        if (created_by = (select id from users where role_id=2),type_id=1, internal_status_id=2 , status='STL')
            then set new.status='FINANCE';  
        elseif (status<>'STL',internal_status_id<>2,type_id<>1) 
            then set new.status='status';
        end if;
```

When I save the record in transaction table , it returns error message as

> SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: (conn=253) Unknown column `created_by` in 'field list' . The Field created_byis a valid field which exists in the transaction table.

The previous post [MySQL Trigger Check if Row Field Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44191940/mysql-trigger-check-if-row-field-exists) does not answer the above query.

Transactions table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   internal_status_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  type_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  created_by bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY transactions_int_status_FK (internal_status_id),
  KEY transactions_type_fk (type_id),
  KEY transactions_assigned_created_by_fk (created_by),
  CONSTRAINT transactions_assigned_created_by_fk FOREIGN KEY (created_by) REFERENCES users (id),
  CONSTRAINT transactions_type_FK FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES transaction_types (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

User Table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  role_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY user_user_name_un (user_name),
  KEY users_fk (role_id),
  CONSTRAINT user_role_fk FOREIGN KEY (role_id) REFERENCES roles (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=142 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: a) You must refer to a table or pseudotable. I.e. not `... if (created_by = ...` but, for example, `... if (NEW.created_by = ...`. The same for all another column names. b) The conditions must be combined by proper logical operators (AND, OR, etc.), not by a comma.

Comment: @Akina- Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You use `.. if (created_by = ..`. What `created_by` do you want to refer? taken from where? a column without table name or table context refers to nothing. *Could you please elaborate?* Describe the task in details.

Comment: @Akina- `created_by` is a foreign key to User table. I have posted the DDL of both the tables (transactions and Users)

Comment: Again. `created_by` in the trigger **MUST** have the table specified (explicitly or contextually). In your case it is **NOT** specified. The column itself, not column in table, cannot exist, cannot have a value, cannot be used in expression.